Get the count of unique words in a file using grep and wc
need command to find the count of unique words in a file using grep
Tried using grep along with uniq and sort but need to find a way to use only grep and wc commands.these are the two ways in which am able to do but i need to do using only grep..
$ grep -oE '\w+' 'file.txt' | sort | uniq | wc -l
$ grep -oE '\w+' 'file.txt' > temp.txt && awk '!seen[$0]++' temp.txt | wc -l

Sample input file:
one two three four five
two four one six
eight three seven five

Output:
unique word count: 8
Is it possible to first extract the words using the grep -oE '\w+' file.txt command then perform grep on each word to an empty file and append the word to the file if grep does not find the word to exist in that file.this way only those words which are not found in the new file will get appended to it? is it possible to do this using grep ?

Can you please add a minimal (5-10 rows) example with your expected output?

@AndreWildberg  i have added the expected output

Great, thanks! So the file has only words, some on one line, but also with newlines?

@AndreWildberg yes the file has only words like a paragraph with multiple lines containing words

By the way, 1) sort | uniq = sort -u and 2) grep -oE '\w+' 'file.txt' > temp.txt && awk '!seen[$0]++' temp.txt = grep -oE '\w+' 'file.txt' | awk '!seen[$0]++'.

why can't you use sort? is this some sort of homework/lab assignment and if so what are the complete requirements/limitations? are you expected to do all of this with just grep and wc?

@markp-fuso just trying to extend the functionality of grep without using sort. The requirement is to just get the count of unique words in a file with just grep and wc maybe can also use find

"When a distinguished but elderly scientist states that something is possible, he is almost certainly right. When he states that something is impossible, he is very probably wrong."

@jhnc fair enough, I wasn't considering the more esoteric scenarios that might be possible with GNU grep and its extensions given some important caveats!

Since your grep has -o I shall assume it also has -P and -z:
grep -zPo '(?s)(\b\w+\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)' file.txt |
grep -zc ^


use -z to make grep treat the entire file as a single "line" (since there should be no nulls in it)
use -P to enable Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE) which allow lookaround assertions
(?s) - tell PCRE that . should also match newlines
use a negative lookahead (?! ... ) to find the final occurrence of each word (i.e. word not followed by anything followed by itself)

\b\w+\b and \b\1\b exclude partial words


we use a lookahead so that the lookahead text is not consumed by the match and can be reused when looking for more final words
use -o to output each match on its own "line" (because of -z, nulls are used as the line ending character)
take the generated list of unique words and output the count of "lines"

This will be very slow on larger files.

I'm now thinking a bit about what that script does. According to the GNU grep man page about -P "This option is experimental when combined with the -z (--null-data) option", Do you know if anything in the above is fragile in that context?

@EdMorton given that the RE suffers from catastrophic backtracking, fragility is the least of its issues

@EdMorton regex101 hits 40M steps for 3500 word input and times out with 4000, so much beyond that and this is likely to break

well, the OP just asked if it could be done, not if it could be done robustly, portably, efficiently, reliably, etc. so IMO it's a good answer :-).

yes, for any significantly sized input, just using sort -u is much more robust

TIL -o is not in POSIX grep

Since awk is also tagged, an approach using only (almost any) awk, returning the length of an associative array, where the indices are the words.
% awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){A[$i]++}} END{print length(A)}' file
8

Tested with

GNU awk 3.1.8/4.2.1/5.3.0
nawk 20221215
original awk 20121220
mawk 20240123


What you want to do is impossible with just grep or grep+wc (unless you use GNU grep with its extensions and caveats per @jhnc's answer).
Given that, if you really just want to use one tool then using GNU Awk for multi-char RS and assuming a file of space-separated "words" as input:
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{unq[$0]} END{print "unique word count:", length(unq)}' file.txt
unique word count: 8

or using your regexp for identifying a "word":
$ awk -v RS='\\w+' 'RT{unq[RT]} END{print "unique word count:", length(unq)}' file.txt
unique word count: 8

